# Loading a tileset in Phaser game

Tags: javascript, import, phaser-framework

I'm new to Phaser and try to do a top-down game. I followed several tutorials and asked ChatGPT, but I can't manage to use a tilemap I created (using Tiled).

Here is my code :

main.js

```
import Phaser from "./lib/phaser.js";
import Game from "./scenes/Game.js";

export default new Phaser.Game({
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  scene: Game,
  scale: {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
  },
});
```

Game.js

```
import Phaser from "../lib/phaser.js";

export default class Game extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super("game");
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON({
      key: "level1Map",
      url: "../../assets/level1.json",
    });
    this.load.image({ key: "tiles", url: "../../assets/MasterSimple.png" });
  }
  create() {
    const level1Map = this.make.tilemap({ key: "level1Map" });
    const tileset = level1Map.addTilesetImage("Level 1", "tiles");
  }
}
```

```
The error :
phaser.js:133642 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2')
    at AssignTileProperties (phaser.js:133642:48)
    at ParseJSONTiled (phaser.js:133583:5)
    at Parse (phaser.js:133447:22)
    at ParseToTilemap (phaser.js:67019:23)
    at GameObjectCreator.tilemap (phaser.js:210257:12)
    at Game.create (Game.js:15:33)
    at SceneManager.create (phaser.js:100338:26)
    at SceneManager.loadComplete (phaser.js:100250:14)
    at LoaderPlugin.emit (phaser.js:1908:35)
    at LoaderPlugin.loadComplete (phaser.js:196794:14)
```

I tried to edit the path ,to log the first loading in the console, the object seems to be correctly imported.

Comment: how does the folder structure look like? did ou checkout this [official demo](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/tilemap/tiled%20json%20map.js)?

Comment: btw.: how does your tiled file look like? how did you export it? not all export variants are supported.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help !

I found the error cause : it is needed to active the checkbox "embed in map" in Tiled... Now I got the warnings 
`phaser.js:67015 No map data found for key map`
`phaser.js:135410 Invalid Tileset Image: tiles`

Comment: why `map` is  the name of your map not `level1Map`?

Comment: You mean the key ? I'm not sure this affects the import

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to set the "embed in map" option in Tiled.

Thanks everyone